# What is difference between SavedModelBundle.session() and a new Session(graph)?

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-serving

I would like to train a model using python and use it using java with tensorflow.

What is difference between savedModelBundle.session() which is loaded from saved model 
and a new Session(graph) which the graph get from savedModelBundle.graph()?

Thanks,

Youngho

Answer (score 1):

SavedModelBundle's session already comes with the initialization ops described in the SavedModel's MetaGraphDef collections already run. Whereas `new Session(graph)` still requires you to run those manually.